# jQuery Keyup Never Entered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, servlets

I am trying to implement an autocomplete capability on an input form in a project that I am working on. I am attempting to use jQuery to trigger an AJAX call to a servlet, and have added a listener on the input field for keyup. However, it appears that it is never entered. I added console logs also to verify that it was indeed not being entered and checking the console it is also blank.

I've included the html below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Fabflix Home</TITLE>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#autoSearch" ).on("keyup", function () {
    console.log("Entered!");
    var data = $('#autoSearch').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/FabflixP4/servlet/autocomplete",
        data: data,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log("Success!");
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
</HEAD>

<BODY BGCOLOR="#FDF5E6">
<H1 ALIGN="CENTER">Test</H1>

<div align="CENTER">
<form action = "/FabflixP4/servlet/Movie">
    Search: <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="title">
    <input type="submit" id="autoSearch" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I am new to both jQuery and AJAX and figured there is something I am missing. I've spent a few hours now researching this to no avail. As a side not this is a small project not intended for use and performance is not important. Thank you.

Edit1: Added script type and moved to head, still never being entered.

Comment: a quick look at your markup shows some ir-regularities, specify the `typr` of script tag and move it inside the `head` and see if it *works*

Comment: @John Changed to your advice, still not being entered and no output to console.

Comment: Set an id attribute for text input not submit button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are listening to the `keyup` event of the `submit` button. You should listen to the `keyup` event of the `text` input.

```
$('input[name="title"]').on("keyup", function () {
```